# ReadFile image and then overwrite it - A generic error occurred in GDI

Tags: c#, image, gdi+, readfile, overwrite

I just can't get my head around how to solve this problem.
Tried most of suggestions I've found with no success.

```
newMember.Me_Photo = ReadFile("C:/Users/Leta/Documents/Visual Studio 2012/Projects/PkExtreme/tempImage.jpg");
(new Bitmap("C:/Users/Leta/Documents/Visual Studio 2012/Projects/PkExtreme/PkExtreme/initialMemberPic1.jpg")).Save("C:/Users/Leta/Documents/Visual Studio 2012/Projects/PkExtreme/tempImage.jpg");
```

There is a default image which is being used if user does not specify otherwise, and after that it is to be overwritten with another which is basically default image.

Comment: Do you get the exception when calling `new Bitmap` or when you call `.Save`?

Comment: If you want help then you should say which function call throws the exception. And giving the definition of ReadFile would help too.

Comment: It happens in second line, when attempted to save the image. ReadFile takes string argument.

I overcame this error by adding if condition and checking whether user has defined the image. If he has then the first line is executed, otherwise this line is executed:

`newMember.Me_Photo = ReadFile("C:/Users/Leta/Documents/Visual Studio 2012/Projects/PkExtreme/PkExtreme/initialMemberPic1.jpg");`

Answer (score 0):

Your problem may be due to this directory:

```
"C:/Users/Leta/Documents/Visual Studio 2012/Projects/PkExtreme/PkExtreme/initialMemberPic1.jpg"
```

Notice that you have two /PkExtreme subfolders. If this directory (with two PkExtreme subfolders) does not actually exist on disk, you may receive a generic GDI error.

Comment: They do exist. I tried deleting tempImage.jpg and then copying initialMemberPic1.jpg but got error saying that the tempImage.jpg is being used by some other source...